# Developing HTML5 application with Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, html

I am looking for a good IDE for developing HTML5 applications.
I understand that I can do that with Eclipse, which I already use in my developments.

Currently I use Eclipse Helios Release.
Should I download Eclipse Helios Service Release 2, in order to develop HTML5 (with JS)?

Is there anything else I need?
Also - can you recommend me good tutorials for developing HTML5 applications with Eclipse?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [Aptana](http://aptana.com/)?  It's a web-development IDE based on Eclipse.  I've used it for web development in Javascript and HTML, but not specifically HTML5.

Comment: I read some opinions that Aptana is to big and complicated, and that using Eclipse should be enough. What do you think?

Comment: I haven't used basic Eclipse for HTML5 editing, but from what I've read, you need the Java EE installation of Eclipse to do so, which is...kinda big and complicated :)  I would recommend giving them both a try and see which you prefer.  I've really enjoyed working with Aptana, though it certainly can be a bit intimidating with everything it supports.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, I think eclipse would be best suited for HTML5 development since I find it more responsive than Aptana. You also have the advantage of working with Java, PHP, Ruby, and Python server-side scripting in the same IDE you use to develop HTML5 apps. For me that is a must since a lot of code on my sites lay on the server-side for managing posts and such. Go for aptana, just install the software from the repository and you're good to go. Also install the Javascript, PHP, and web installations.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's always Dreamweaver... been using it since 10+ years. Hevan't tried with html5 yet but should work - at least you get a WYSIWYG editor, somethign I haven't seen in Eclipse yet :-(

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [www.html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com) for more information about HTML5. Its developed and maintained by google.

Comment: Funny noob lol "developed and maintained by google". No it's managed and controlled by the W3C.

Comment: @LukeStoneHm I think he's talking about www.html5rocks.com

Comment: how is html5rocks related to an HTML5 IDE discussion?