# How to start on my HTML5 application?

Tags: android, html

I want to start my new project in HTML5 but actually I've no idea to start also I don't have any idea if I must use Dreamweaver or Eclipse? 
My program that I want to design has to do 3 things :

- Register form for people to a MySQL database
- Auto log in once they are registered
- Show information for a MySQL database

Databases are already running on my server but now I need to create the HTML5 files.

Anybody who can give me push in the back ?

Comment: it depends on what the application does! maybe if you tell us a little bit about your project, we may be able to point out some interesting readings.

Comment: Are you asking how to learn HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Whether HTML 5 works or not will depend on browsers on which your site runs . You can use any text editor or IDE to write your HTML 5 code.
You should provide mechanism to detect whether browser supports HTML 5 and if not , render corresponding HTML 4 file.

A comparison test of browsers supporting HTML 5 [here](http://deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/)

Answer (score 1):

[Developing HTML5 application with Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9636125/developing-html5-application-with-eclipse-ide) or 
[html5 for Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/html5)

Comment: Hello,The application is realy " simple" 
Users has to register
once the are in they can see the data that would be downloaded from a sql server .